# How can I migrate Exchange Groups to Google Groups?

Tags: ldap, google-workspace, google-groups

I'm looking for a way to migrate data from LDAP-hosted groups to Google Groups.

With GCDS only the users are migrated, but I would like to migrate the data, do you know any way?

Thanks team

Answer (score 0):

I've migrate groups between different directories using custom-written scripts. This requires some type of mapping between IDs. That is I know the fully qualified DN of each member within the LDAP-hosted group, I can match that up to a record in the new directory -- e.g. cn=lisa,ou=users,o=example has uid lisaj, and there's a corresponding account with the logon id lisaj in the new directory. I've had to do migrations where there was no direct correlation available within the two directories, and successfully linked the two systems using a text file with cross-reference info. A line in the file might say "lisaj     019485-B9184A-9284C-1949" to map my user id in the old system to a record identifier in the new one.

Basic process:

- Connect to source LDAP
- Find all in-scope groups For each in-scope group, get member list
- Find the corresponding group in the new directory (if none exists,
  create it)
- For each member, find corresponding account in new
  directory
- Add member to group in new directory
  (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert
  for Google Groups,
  https://github.com/alfasin/Google-Admin-Directory-API has some Python
  examples)

As a one-off process, it's pretty simple. If you need the two directories to remain in sync for some time, the script becomes a little more complicated. Assuming the old directory is "authoritative" (the one with the 'right' data -- and you can only make changes in one of the directories, otherwise it's impossible to tell which members actually should be in the group), you need to check the new directory group for any members that *aren't* a member of the old directory group and remove them as well as add any old directory group members that aren't in the new directory group yet. I generally add a "last modified" constraint to the filter used to locate groups in the old directory -- e.g. find all group objects where the lastModified timestamp is in the past 24 hrs -- to avoid continually reprocessing data for groups that haven't changed.